# Asp.net MVC talking to SharePoint from a diffenent server

Tags: visual-studio, 2013, mvc

Ok, so I want to build a internet facing asp.net MVC application, place it on server X in my domain, and i want this application to be able to talk Server Y,where SharePoint 2013 is installed.
I want my mvc application to be able to do CRUD on some of the lists in SharePoint.

So could any of you point me in the right direction? Should I call SharePoint 2013 Web Services library from within my mvc application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use SharePoint web services unless a new feature is introduced in SharePoint 2013 and am not aware of it.

For what you want you can use Rest API for CRUD operations on a list,

[Get started with the SharePoint 2013 REST service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp142380.aspx)

OR

[SharePoint 2013: Use the cross-domain library and REST for CRUD operations](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SharePoint-2013-Use-the-f86d99f3/sourcecode?fileId=76615&pathId=98357527)

OR

[How to: Complete basic operations using SharePoint 2013 client library code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179912.aspx#BasicOps_SPCSOMOps)